# PHP default Post value

Tags: php, php-7

I have some simple code what gets user inserted parameters. But how can I use `$_POST` to set a default value? For example, if a user is asked to input name and age and he chose to input only the name I need that `$_POST` sets age to 0.

My code what I use:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$weight= $_POST['weight'];
$size =   $_POST['size'];
```

And sometimes there can be only weight or size so I need to set up default value. I tried `$size =   $_POST['size'] ?? 0;` but it not worked.

Comment: In what way didn't it work?

Comment: `??` worked in php 7+

Comment: It did not set any value. I have PHP 7.0.23

Comment: I think you might need !empty($_POST['name'])

Comment: Little offtopic, but - PHP's filter functions might be worth a look - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/) to set default values for non-required fields.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$weight= (!empty($_POST['weight'])) ? $_POST['weight'] : 0;
$size =   (!empty($_POST['size'])) ? $_POST['size'] : 0;
```

Reference:-

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

***Note:-*** You can do same for `name` also like:-

```
$name = (!empty($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

***Remark:-*** [Null coalescing operator `??`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) only worked in php `7+`

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Sorry, my fault I didn't see you use an !empty option.

Answer (score 4):

The `isset()` function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. If a variable is already unset with unset() function, it will no longer be set. The `isset()` function return false if testing variable contains a NULL value.

Version:
PHP 4 and above

Test Code :

```
$name =  isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$weight= isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : 0;
$size =  isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$size = (isset($_POST['size'])) ? $_POST['size'] : 0;
```

Comment: When i was posting answer there was not answered by anyone.

Comment: Regardless, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.